# SSL Handshake Failure Error

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, axis

I have also tried the following way, but it dosent work.

```
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol"); 
Security.addProvider (new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider()); 
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,TLSv1"); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "");
Security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", ""); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", ""); 
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");
```

But the above approach gives me Handshake failure error. 
I am properly importing certificates and private key is there in pfx file which i am using in keystore settings.

Comment: Unless you are still using Java 1.3, you should remove the first two lines. Then retest. If it still fails, post the *complete* stack trace. So far you haven't even posted the error message, which is of no use.

Comment: The problem got solved..just tried with the new keystores and truststores. we were using java 1.5 only

Comment: Got solved how? Do tell.

Comment: Actually initially i was using the trusstore as jssecacerts which was generated by one of the class file available on internet...and keystore i used as pfx file..but later i created a separate trustore and a keystore..then problem solved...

Comment: HI All, after this my other services are not working and when i switch back to original jssecacerts/cacerts it works. Actually i created a new truststore file which only contains certificates of particular service and not for all. i have triel all approches using keystool utility  but no luck..

Comment: No. Obviously you *haven't* 'tried all approaches' at all, as you haven't found the approach that works.

Comment: HI EJP, i did the SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(protocolVersion); context.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null); SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory(); SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory secureProtocolSocketFactory = new SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory(context); Protocol.registerProtocol("https", new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory)secureProtocolSocketFactory, port)); Is this correct...??? this class "SslContextedSecureProtocolSocketFactory " i got from one of the jars available on internet and just used..will this work..??

Comment: I don't know how I am expected to read that mess. Suppose you edit it into your question where it will be at least partly intelligible?

Comment: did u guys came to any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same was resolved by adding the certificates to cacerts file and pointing the same to weblogic.
Intially certificates chain was not properly imported into cacerts file.
Or you can create your own truststore and make changes in application server.